# Restart a remote windows service using batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, batch-file

Haloo all,

I am having couple of windows services running at different Servers which will execute at predefined set of time periods.

Some times it may happen that service is not functioning as desired, then I will go and restart that particular service. After that it will start functioning.

Currently using SQL Stored Procedure and SQL Jobs every 30 mins system will be checking whether the service is functioning or not and if it is not functioning then it will trigger a dbmail to my ID as a notification. (There is a table in my data base in that I will be getting the last executed date and time).

My question is, is there any way like.....using the SQL job I can restart these windows service directly...using a batch file or something...Please note that the SQL database is not on the same server in which the Windows service is running....But all these servers are connected by WAN.

Comment: **S**ervice **C**ontrol utility does it: `sc \\your_server stop` (to stop it) and `sc \\your_server start` (to re-start it)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a bat file that does a "stop" or "restart" or "start" for the services you want . "sc \servername stop servicename" or "sc \servername start servicename" or "sc \servername restart servicename". This bat file can be executed remotely or directly on the server, you can then call this bat file using a sql job or using a windows task scheduler. Back in the day, all of our server management was done using VBScript or DOS, via bat files.